# Replacing HTML with JavaScript changed style, images no longer in-line horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to coding and I replaced some repetitive HTML with JavaScript and now the images, which used to display 4 across, are no longer displaying horizontally. They now display on the left only. I've tried replacing float left in the child div with float left in the parent div, display: inline block, and display: inline. How can I get it to display 4 across again?

```
<section class= "gal">
<script src="./gallery.js"></script
      <!---<div class="img" id="picture">
          <img class="img-zoom" src="./images/ore1.png" alt="" width="300"     height="200">
          <div class="desc">Turquoise Nugget Earrings</div>
  </div>

  <div class="img">
      <img class="img-zoom" src="./images/ore9.png" alt="" width="300" height="200">
      <div class="desc">Black Cinnabar Earrings</div>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
      <img class="img-zoom" src="./images/ore11.png" alt="" width="300" height="200">
      <div class="desc">White Shell Earrings</div>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
      <img class="img-zoom" src="./images/ore12.png" alt="" width="300" height="200">
      <div class="desc">White Shell and Flower Charm Earrings</div>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
      <img class="img-zoom" src="./images/ore13.png" alt="" width="300" height="200">
      <div class="desc">Light Green Resin Earrings</div>
  </div>--->
```

Here is the CSS:

```
section.gal {

}
div.img {
    margin: 15px;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;

}

div.img:hover {

}

div.img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.img-zoom {
    width: 500px;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.transition {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2); 
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -o-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

And the Java Script:

```
    var galleryImages = [
['ore1', 'Turquoise Nugget Earrings'],
['ore9', 'Black Cinnabar Earrings'],
['ore11' 'White Shell Earrings'], 
['ore12', 'White Shell and Flower Charm Earrings']
];

function print(message) {
    var pictureDiv = document.getElementById ('picture');
    pictureDiv.innerHTML = message;
}

function displayImages(list) {
    var listHTML = '<div class="img">';
    for (var i = 0; i<list1.length; i +=1) {
        listHTML += '<img class="img-zoom" src="./images/' + list[i][0] + '.png" alt="" width="300" height="200">';
        listHTML += '<div class="desc">' + list[i][1] + '</div>';

    }
    listHTML += '</div>';
    print(listHTML);
}

displayImages (galleryImages);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your original HTML has a `<div class="img">` wrapper around every individual image. Your JavaScript code, however, only creates one outer wrapper and it goes around **all** the images.

You can fix that by simply appending that markup inside the loop instead of outside:

```
var listHTML = "";
for (var i = 0; i<list1.length; i +=1) {
    listHTML += '<div class="img">';
    listHTML += '<img class="img-zoom" src="./images/' + list[i][0] + '.png" alt="" width="300" height="200">';
    listHTML += '<div class="desc">' + list[i][1] + '</div>';
    listHTML += "</div>";
}

print(listHTML);
```